Can't control servo with Python using Raspberry Pi
I am using a Raspberry Pi model 4B and a Tower Pro servo SG51R which only turns 180 degrees. I am writing code on the Raspberry Pi to control the servo (which works as I have tested it with my Arduino Uno, it responds and works correctly) with Python.
I installed the gpiozero library successfully on my Raspberry Pi using the below commands:
sudo apt-get install python3-rpi.gpio
sudo pip install gpiozero

I then connected my servo to the Raspberry Pi similar to the diagram shown below

I made sure the brown wire connected to GND, the red wire to a 4.8 volt power supply. and the yellow (PWM) wire to the GPIO 25 pin (pin 22).
I then ran the below code:
from gpiozero import Servo
 
test = Servo(25) # Connected servo to this pin (pin 22)
print('moving')

test.max()
print('done moving')

from time import sleep

sleep(1)
print('moving again')

test.min()
print('finished second movement')
 
sleep(5)
 
test.value = 0
 
sleep(1)
test.value = 1
 
sleep(1)
test.value = -1
 
print('done entirely')

and received the below output:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py:1532: PWMSoftwareFallback: To reduce servo jitter, use the pigpio pin factory.See https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#servo for more info
  warnings.warn(PWMSoftwareFallback(
moving
done moving
moving again
finished second movement
done entirely

Yet the servo still does not move. I even tried using a different servo of the same model, and using different pins to no avail. Is there anything else I'm missing? How could I make this work?

What's under that link? What is this 22 magic number?

22 is the pin number I've connected my servo's PWM wire to.

For those curious, I ended up getting around this issue by connecting the Raspberry Pi to an Arduino Uno which controlled the servos. To connect them, I just sent a signal (voltage) from the Raspberry Pi into the Arduino Uno, corresponding to the movement of a servo - not ideal, but it works
